# How to build a universal bundle for MacOS on Apple Silicon electron-builder?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, apple-silicon

I am trying to create a universal bundle with electron-builder.

On an Intel based mac (with electron-builder v22.*) it does this automatically.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing on an m1 mac (with electron-builder v23.0.2). However it  automatically creates two bundles (One for Intel and another for arm64).

The app makes use of a binary file that was compiled specifically for Intel based macs (but works fine on Apple Silicon in the universal bundle via Rosetta).

For now we need to continue shipping a universal bundle.
How can I force electron-builder to continue building one universal bundle?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I need to build a Universal binary on my new Apple M1 mac, that will run on Intel Macs.   I'm using electron-packager.  I've been googling for a while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

With electron-builder, you can specify target architectures in **package.json**:

```
{
  "build": {
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "mas",
          "arch": [
            "universal"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "mas-dev"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation for this is buried in the [CLI page](https://www.electron.build/cli#target).

Answer (score 0):

[Electron Universal](https://github.com/electron/universal) that what you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33261532)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get electron-builder to create a universal bundle on my M1 Mac no matter what I tried.

In the end I realized that the x64 binary is automatically run by Rosetta when the app is installed on a Mac with a M1 chip.
So I decided to go ahead and create two separate builds for Intel and Apple Silicon.

In my package.json file I modified my script like this:

```
"release:mac": "electron-builder --mac --x64 --arm64 --publish 'onTagOrDraft'",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `--universal` flag when building/publishing your apps.
That's what I use today for my app:
`electron-builder --mac --universal --publish`
FYI, using electron-builder `v23.0.2`

Comment: Just some extra information, `electron-builder --mac --universal --publish always` Using `--publish always` ensures that whenever you run the Electron Builder command with this flag, the built application will be published to the defined publishing platform (such as GitHub releases, an S3 bucket, or other distribution mechanisms specified in your configuration). This way, the new version of your app will be available for distribution after each build, regardless of the build type or environment.